# Is there any way to avoid unphar from phar file (PHP Archive)?

Tags: php, phar

There is a nice tool available in php to archive php files in "phar" format to make it easily distribution and installation. It can make a single "phar" file of the whole php folder. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php

And phar files can be easily "unphar" to its original folder using tools like
http://unphar.com

Now, my question is that is there any way that we can add some password or random salt while generating phar file so that it can not be unphar easily? My motive is to protect the php script from alteration.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't prevent users from extracting phar contents.

What you can do is encoding the php files in there (e.g. with ioncube) or simply minify them, so that they are unreadable. But all measurements won't protect you from the determined hacker.